# How to programmatically select rows in CFGRID with multiselectrow on CF9.01+?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, extjs3, coldfusion-10, cfgrid

Why's there `ColdFusion.grid.getSelectedRows` but no `setSelectedRows()`?

Doc: [Adobe ColdFusion 10 * ColdFusion.grid.getSelectedRows](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/CFMLRef/WSaad0660b0585370c5e0a1d2c132ed6578ec-8000.html)

Then how shall one select rows programmatically???

Sigh... gotta be careful with `<cfgrid>` before I hit the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about 9.0.1, but in CF10 try [selectRange](http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/docs/output/Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel.html#selectRange) or [selectRecords](http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/docs/output/Ext.grid.RowSelectionModel.html#selectRecords).

```
var grid = ColdFusion.Grid.getGridObject('myGrid');
var model = grid.getSelectionModel();

model.selectRange(4, 6, false);
// ... or
var records = [grid.store.getAt(10)];
model.selectRecords(records , true);
```